# Speed of calculations in SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I've got a database (MySQL) table with three fields :  id, score, and percent.

Long story short, I need to do a calculation on each record that looks like this:

(Score * 10) / (1 - percent) = Value

And then I need to use that value both in my code and as the ORDER BY field.  Writing the SQL isn't my issue - I'm just worried about the efficiency of this statement.  Is doing that calculation in my SQL statement the most efficient use of resources, or would I be better off grabbing the data and then doing math via PHP?

If SQL is the best way to do it, are there any tips I can keep in mind for keeping my SQL pulls as speedy as possible?

**Update 1:** Just to clear some things up, because it seems like many of the answers are assuming differently :  Both the Score and the Percent will be changing constantly.  Actually, just about every time a user interacts with the app, those fields will change (those fields are actually linked to a user, btw).

As far as # of records, right now it's very small, but I would like to be scaling for a target set of about 2 million records (users).  At any given time I will only need 20ish records, but I need them to be the top 20 records sorted by this calculated value.

Comment: you could ad another field to the db with this value, calculate it when you add or update the data. Have you benchmarked how long it takes now?

Comment: Use MySQL's "explain" function to look at the time executions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like this calculated value is of inherent meaning in your business domain; if this is the case, I would calculate it once (e.g. at the time the record is created), and use it just like any normal field. This is by far the most efficient way to achieve what you want - the extra calculation on insert or update has minimal performance impact, and from then on you don't have to worry about who does the calculation where. 
Drawback is that you do have to update your "insert" and "update" logic to perform this calculation. I don't usually like triggers - they can be the source of impenetrable bugs - but this is a case where I'd consider them (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

If for some reason you can't do that, I'd suggest doing it on the database server. This should be pretty snappy, unless you are dealing with very large numbers of records; in that case the "order by" will be a real performance problem. It will be a far bigger performance problem if you execute the same logic on the PHP side, of course - but your database tends to be the bottleneck from a performance point of view, so the impact is larger.
If you're dealing with large numbers of records, you may just have to bite the bullet and go with my first suggestion.

If it weren't for the need to sort by the calculation, you could also do this on the PHP side; however, sorting an array in PHP is not something I'd want to do for large result sets, and it seems wasteful not to do sorting in the database (which is good at that kinda thing).

So, after all that, my actual advice boils down to:

- do the simplest thing that could work
- test whether it's fast enough within the constraints of your
  project
- if not, iteratively refactor to a faster solution, re-test
- once you reach "good enough", move on.

Based on **edit 1**:

You've answered your own question, I think - returning (eventually) 2 million rows to PHP, only to find the top 20 records (after calculating their "value" one by one) will be incredibly slow. So calculating in PHP is really not an option.

So, you're going to be calculating it on the server. My recommendation would be to create a view (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) which has the SQL to perform the calculation; benchmark the performance of the view with 200, 200K and 2M records, and see if it's quick enough.

If it isn't quick enough at 2M users/records, you can always create a regular table, with an index on your "value" column, and relatively little needs to change in your client code; you could populate the new table through triggers, and the client code might never know what happened.

Comment: It sounds like just adding another database field might be the answer.  The field will be changing a lot, which is why I first thought it would be better to calculate it on the fly, but now I'm having second thoughts.  I put some more updated information in my question: does that help you narrow down to a certain solution?

Answer (score 1):

doing the math in **the database will be more efficient** because sending the data back and forth from the database to the client will be slower than that simple expression no matter how fast the client is and how slow the database is.

Comment: His query doesn't involve any "back and forth".. he'll only send the data once.  Additionally, your claim that "no matter how fast the client is and how slow the database is" makes no difference is simply wrong.  In his case, it's probably true, but "no matter" is simply an overstatement.  Suppose he wanted to calculate an MD5 sum... that's a pretty complex operation that could not be easily expressed in an SQL statement (of course it could be in a stored procedure, in most DB engines).

Comment: the comparison that i meant is "sending the data over the pipe to a client" versus "several arithmetic operations". i'm not talking about factoring large prime numbers :) hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Test it out and let us know the performance results.  I think it is going to depend on the volume of data in your result set.  For the SQL bit, just make sure your where clause has a covered index.

Answer (score 0):

Where you do the math shouldn't be too important.  It's the same fundamental operation either way.  Now, if MySQL is running on a different server than your PHP code, then you may care which CPU does the calculation.  You may wish that the SQL server does more of the "hard work", or you may wish to leave the SQL server doing "only SQL", and move the math logic to PHP.

Another consideration might be bandwidth usage (if MySQL isn't running on the same machine as PHP)--you may wish to have MySQL return whichever form is shorter, to use less network bandwidth.

If they're both on the same physical hardware, though, it probably makes no noticeable difference, from a sheer CPU usage standpoint.

One tip I would offer is to do the ORDER BY on the raw value (percent) rather than on the calculated value--this way MySQL can use an index on the percent column--it can't use indexes on calculated values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a growing number of records, your script (and its memory) will reach its limits faster than mysql would. Are you planning to fetch all records anyway?
Mysql would be quicker in general.
I don't get how you would use the value calculated in php in an ORDER BY afterwards. If you are planning to sort in php, it would become even slower but it all depends on the number of records you're dealing with.